# How to efficiently browse OpenCV repository to understand the code?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am relatively new to coding and I apologize if my questions are straightforward to you.

I am trying to understand OpenCV code to be able to add my contributions (mainly converting 2D tools to 3D as it would be useful for my machine learning projects and for medical projects). There is also some extra-curiosity since I like to understand how things work.

1) On the example of the GaussianBlur method. What happens when I call it in Python? Namely, how the Python code is bind to the C++ one? When I browse the repository, there are all C++ files, and I do not find where it is done. When I installed cv2 with pip all was automatic, but I would like to understand the process.

2) if I want to understand the whole GaussianBlur algorithm, I am also not familiar with C++ browsing, so how should I proceed to retrieve what files are used (methods and also inherited classes).
I've found on another answer that https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9c23f2f1a682faa9f0b2c2223a857c7d93ba65a6/modules/imgproc/src/smooth.cpp#L4085 contains the method, but how can I find any method on my own? Why isn't it in the master folder but in the blob folder? How to find then the other methods or classes called by this one?

3) this is more a curiosity question since I am not familiar with makefiles, but when is done the binding between Python and C++? When I install OpenCV with pip it is done automatically, but I would like to understand the process.

Thanks a lot for your answers! I would appreciate any tutorial since I've googled a lot before asking, of course, but did not find what could help me on my own.

Comment: May I ask what IDE you are using?

Comment: I'm just browsing the GitHub repository. Otherwise, I use Jupyter Notebook for Python and Visual Studio Code for C++

Comment: You should clone the code to open it in your IDEs. It will simplify the process of browsing code significantly. To understand the c++ code you can search for a function you want to find e.g. `ctrl + F` -> `gaussian`. You will find the function definition and can read through the code. If you find something interesting inside that function you can simply press the `right mouse button` and then `go to definition`

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) to understand how you can create a python module from c++ and how it is then used inside of python

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have to **download the library and link them** in the compilation and linking process (when creating an executable from source code).

The C++ bind is done with **`python.h` library for c++**. using this binding OpenCV module is created for python.

For learning **gaussian blur**, etc. you can learn **image processing**.

The methods of Opencv are kept in their respective files. like `opencv2/highgui.hpp` **for OpenCV GUI** like `imshow`. you can import them to C++ with `#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>`(the methods are separated to different files to reduce importing unnecessary methods).

CMake is like a scripting language(its a tool) where you can *write a script on how the tool should build the executable from source code*.

The starter tutorial is [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SM5OD2pZKY)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, using OpenCV doesn't cause me problems, neither does GaussianBlur, it's more understanding the code, how to find another method's code, how to efficiently browse the repo that I want to understand

Comment: OpenCV in c++ is similar to python OpenCV, the *methods have been split between files*. you can use the **search box** or **index** in **[here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/genindex.html)** to search for the required functionality. *I use Google to find things that i can't find here.* To browse the methods code go to source code in [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv)